# The plan for [grammar]

Tags: discussion, tagging, retagging

The tag [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) is one of our most highly-used tags, though it is, unfortunately, so vague as to be nearly useless. I submit the following proposal as a way to break up this tag into something useful.

1. Following [nohat's answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/should-grammaticality-be-a-synonym-of-grammar/764#764), questions about the grammatical acceptability of a particular sentence or construction should be tagged [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality), as many questions already are.
2. Questions about the meaning of grammar terms or the names of specific constructions should be tagged [grammatical-terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-terminology) (new).
3. Questions about the grammatical analysis of a particular sentence or construction should be tagged [grammatical-analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-analysis) (new). Furthermore, [syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) should be made a synonym of this tag.
4. Questions tagged [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) which fit into none of these categories should be tagged with something more descriptive. Plain old [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) should be abolished as it succumbs too easily to tag rot.

The floor is open for comments and additional suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

I'd kind of be more in favor of double-tagging, i.e. keep [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), but add [terminology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) and/or [analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) (or whatever) as appropriate. (And, as Alenanno said, keep [syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) separate, because it is. Separate, that is.) But I don't feel particularly strongly either way.

(And obviously, [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) should be removed from questions to which it does not apply.)

Comment: After some thought, I think I like this best. A significant number of [grammar] questions need to be [grammaticality], but introducing two new tags is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @JSBangs, If [acceptability] hadn't been renamed to [grammaticality], we wouldn't have this problem. Just sayin'. (Also, my browser marks "grammaticality" as misspelled.)

Answer (score 5):

I support this proposal: we should get rid of the [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag, and we should blacklist it so that it cannot be recreated.  It does not help anything.

Comment: Especially when it's frequently used for punctuation!

Answer (score 4):

**About point #3:** Syntax tag should not be a synonym of "Grammatical analysis" (and actually they're not synonyms), simply because "syntax" is not (about) the analysis, but instead it's the study about the rules and principles about sentences construction and word order. They are two different things.

**About the rest:** I have nothing in particular to say about this, but, yes, the change might help to filter the questions, so people won't just throw their questions into that big "grammar" container.

Comment: We do have a [tag:syntactic-analysis] tag.

Comment: @tchrist Was the syntax tag replaced?

Comment: No, it persists.

Comment: @tchrist I kind of disagree with my own answer, but it's kind of old, not sure I should edit it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Linguistic discovery and analysis should not be about learning an esoteric terminology.  The more hoops you ask questioners to jump through to ask their questions, the worse.