# Rename the [grammar] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As noted in [this four-year-old question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/should-grammaticality-be-a-synonym-of-grammar), the [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag (and also its misspelt cousin, [grammer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer), which I implicitly include here) is the fourth most used tag on ELU, and it seems to be overwhelmingly misused as a generic tag by new users who don’t understand how tagging works and just put in ‘grammar’ no matter what the question is about.

As noted in [this slightly-less-than-four-year-old question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/986/the-plan-for-grammar), that basically makes the tag completely useless. Nohat’s answer in the first question makes a useful distinction:

- [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) is appropriate for questions about whether something is grammatical or not
- [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) is appropriate for more abstract questions about how various grammatical structures are defined and named, or how they function or differ from each other

There are, I suppose, a fair amount of questions that could meaningfully be put into the latter category; but the vast majority of questions currently tagged [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) are either in the former category or belong to some completely different category.

JSBձոգչ’s question seems to have been quite positively received, but nothing appears to have come from it. My suggestion on how to help fix this tag abuse is a bit different from his, though:

**Can we rename the [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag to [grammatical-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-structure) or [grammatical-structures](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-structures)?**

Hopefully if new users see no tag simply titled [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar), they will try to find something a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, we’d also have to blacklist it so it didn’t return.

Comment: Right, I'm thinking it will come back repeatedly as [tag:grammer].

Comment: There are [2443 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/211372/tag-edits) where the [grammar] tag has been edited out as incorrect. There are almost certainly more where that **should** happen!

Comment: [grammatical-structure] is probably no better than [grammar] in terms of finding the tag and using it wrongly. How about [grammar-specification]?

Comment: @Andrew That doesn't seem like a very descriptive tag name to me—I can't think of any circumstance where I'd ask a question and think to search for that. I do think [tag:grammatical-structure] is quite a bit more specific than just [tag:grammar], and that someone who just wants the “question must have at least one tag” warning to go away would not be quite as likely to accept that as they would be with [tag:grammar]—but I may be wrong, of course.

Comment: [grammatical-structure] is more likely to be taken to refer to a sentence's grammatical structure and its correctness (that is, grammaticality). And that means that it will be misused.

Comment: @Andrew Perhaps we should make a tag [tag:grammatically-correct] as a synonym of [tag:grammaticality]. Surely anyone who is asking about whether something is correct or not would be more likely to choose that than [tag:grammatical-structures]?

Comment: How about a syntax tag?

Comment: [[syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)] | [[syntactic-analysis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-analysis)]. If we use [grammatical-structures] (which I see has already been created) then we will have to blacklist [grammatical-structure] to stop that being created and misused.

Comment: Isn't the grammer tag supposed to be for questions about one's maternal grandparent(s)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm open to this idea, and I'd like to know what the rest of the community thinks. I agree with tchrist's comment that renaming it won't make it go away. We'd have to blacklist it so that users didn't keep re-creating it.

I do want to mention that the tag has been helpful as a marker for new users who are likely to need early help. It's not the intended purpose of tags, but I do believe it has been useful for this purpose.

Finally, will it be useful to have all of the grammar tags renamed? If many or most of the posts tagged thus are incorrectly tagged, we should probably instead mount a cleanup effort.

Comment: I agree that a cleanup effort is needed—but I'd say in addition, not instead. Whatever we do, the cleanup effort is probably unavoidable; but if we also get rid of the misused tags, we can hopefully rid ourselves of a great part of _future_ cleanups necessary.

Comment: we won't need to blacklist it if we synonymise it. We just have to pick a good synonym.

Comment: @Matt That won’t get to the root of the problem, though, which is that people (especially new users) think that ‘grammar’ just means ‘all the stuff about language that I don’t know’ and so use [tag:grammar] as a default catch-all tag for just about anything under the sun. The only way to get around that is by making sure that there _is_ no [tag:grammar] tag at all that they can choose, and if we synonymise it, the tag will still show up and can still be misused; we’d just have a different tag we’d have to do major cleanup work on instead.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fair enough, I see your point.

Comment: What if there were more specific tags such as 'grammar-nouns' or 'grammar-partsofspeech' or 'grammar-clauses'? Not sure how those would really be different from the more generic tags, though...

Comment: @miltonaut: What about questions where someone is trying to figure out the *name* of a particular grammar, um, thing?

Comment: After about two weeks, this post stands at 16 upvotes and one downvote; and this answer, supporting it, has four upvotes and no downvotes. What is the next step if this is to actually go through? (I haven’t done any tag-stuff before, really …)

Answer (score 1):

Not all grammar is about "structures" (though if you are a proponent of Minimalism then maybe that's not the case.) Grammar involves syntax, morphology, semantics - it's a broad part of linguistics and includes a lot of things, excepting phonetics and social linguistics.

I think the tag system proposed in [this old question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/986/the-plan-for-grammar) should be implemented instead.

Comment: But both syntax, morphology, semantics, and many other subsets of grammar already have their own tags, and questions that are really about those things should be tagged with those instead.

Comment: “Grammar” is no more useful a tag than would be “language”.

Comment: @tchrist That's why I linked to the old proposal, which says that 'grammar' should be gotten rid of.